# ¿ Como usar condicion if en sentencia update para que no se inserten numeros negativos

Tags: mysql

Soy un poco nueva en la parte de base de datos y requiero usar una condicional if en mi sentencia update.
Lo que deseo es que al ejecutar ese código me valide si hay resultados negativos, si es así que no ingrese el negativo o que ingrese un 0 en vez del negativo mi código es el siguiente

```
UPDATE tareas 
SET Tr_Estado = (100 - DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Tr_FechaFinal) /  DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal)  * 100 ) 
WHERE Tr_Id > 0
```

Comment: Aprendiz , ya intente eso y no me funciona, gracias.

Comment: Ok, lo tendre en cuenta para la proxima

Comment: Si, ya elimine la anterior muchas gracias por tu consejo.

Comment: Por si le sirve a alguien esta es la condicion como se usa
```
UPDATE tareas SET Tr_Estado = (CASE WHEN  Tr_Estado < 0 THEN 0 ELSE (100 - DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Tr_FechaFinal) /  DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal)  * 100 ) END) WHERE Tr_Id > 0
```

Comment: @Angelita ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la definición y estructura de la tabla? Una solución simple sería que `Tr_Estado` sea `UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar IF directo desde la ejecución de un script sql para insertar, te recomiendo que valides el valor antes de que ingrese a MySQL, la otra alternativa es que uses un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, ahí si puedes hacer uso de IF y otros comandos también, luego solo debes llamar al procedimiento almacenado con el parámetro a validar y el procedimiento hará el trabajo que le hallas encomendado.

```
            DELIMITER $$
            DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedute_test
            CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_test(IN parametro VARCHAR(45))
            BEGIN
                IF (parametro>0) THEN
                    INSERT INTO tabla(campo) VALUES (parametro);
                END IF;
            END $$
            DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución muy sencilla es hacer tu campo id con atributo unsigned es decir que solo aceptara positivos puedes hacerlo con la siguiente línea

```
ALTER TABLE `tu_tabla` CHANGE `Id` `Id` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

(Donde dice INT(4) le pones lo que tienes de valor en tu campo Id y tu_tabla pones el nombre de la tabla)

O si estas en phpmyadmin solo ve a estructura y busca el campo que quieras editar y en este caso Id y dale clic en editar, desues en donde dice atributos seleccionas unsigned, le das clic en guardar y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede definir un límite inferior para el valor a actualizar con la [función GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) que devuelve el valor mas grande, si el valor es negativo ( -1250 en el ejemplo ) se toma 0 porque es mas grande.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tareas
    (`Tr_Id` int, `Tr_Estado` int, `Tr_FechaInicio` datetime, `Tr_FechaFinal` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO Tareas
    (`Tr_Id`, `Tr_Estado`, `Tr_FechaInicio`, `Tr_FechaFinal`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, '2020-05-05 00:00:00', '2020-05-1 00:00:00'),
    (2, 0, '2021-03-10 00:00:00', '2020-01-15 00:00:00')
;

UPDATE Tareas 
SET Tr_Estado = GREATEST( 0, ( 
  100 - DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Tr_FechaFinal ) / 
  DATEDIFF(Tr_FechaInicio, Tr_FechaFinal)  * 100 
) )
WHERE Tr_Id > 0;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM Tareas;
```

```
Tr_Id   Tr_Estado   Tr_FechaInicio          Tr_FechaFinal
1       0           2020-05-05T00:00:00Z    2020-05-01T00:00:00Z
2       62          2021-03-10T00:00:00Z    2020-01-15T00:00:00Z
```